# How to use suppress warnings without knowing the specific error type?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, suppress-warnings

I recently ran into a compilation error that was red flagging files as well.

```kotlin
@Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION")
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.spring.framework.boot) apply false
}
```

I know IDEA will suggest what the error type is, but it might not. The example above is caused by a bug in `Android Studio`.

I don't want to waste time trying to figure out which type error it is. After all, if you are lucky you will find it. If you are unlucky, it will take a lot of time, which I think is unnecessary.

But this kind of compilation warning marks the file name in red, and it is difficult for you not to notice it, so it is necessary to eliminate this warning, maybe I have a little obsessive-compulsive disorder.

I'm wondering how to ignore the warning without knowing what the concrete type is, Can you tell me a solution?

1. It is acceptable to ignore warnings using IDE, either `Android Studio` or `IDEA`, because in my opinion these two IDEs have great similarities.
2. It is also acceptable to use `java` language annotations or `kotlin` language annotations
3. It is unacceptable to simply ignore all compilation warnings for the entire project.

###### first edit 2023-3-21

I'm pretty sure this isn't actually a error, if you want you can check [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19369) out for more on this example.

Comment: Just ignoring all warnings on a certain piece of code might also not be the best option as this could swallow warnings you would care about. Don't the logs or error messages tell you which exact warning it would be?

Comment: @Thomas The premise is that you know that this warning is an IDE error or other reasons, which means that this is actually a wrong warning. IDEA prompts an error, but does not provide a value for `@Suppress`

Comment: The issue may be that IDEs have their own sets of checks and configurations on how to handle those. `@SuppressWarnings` is normally understood by the compiler or libraries that are working on the code. IDE-specific warnings would normally be disabled in the project settings and not the code itself (or it would be done via IDE-specific values or approaches which could be something other than `@SupressWarnings`)

Comment: @Thomas Maybe the library is causing it, but I'm not really concerned about where the errors come from, I just want to know how to eliminate them.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me: I didn't refer to causes but who's able to understand the annotations or who is able to detect certain conditions. So if a certain IDE or any other tool is detecting warnings I'd not suppress those right in the code as this might be a very specific setting for that tool or IDE only. Instead, you might need to look into the tool's/IDE's settings. If you just compile on the command line do you get that warning as well?

Comment: Btw, "it is difficult for you not to notice it, so it is necessary to eliminate this warning, maybe I have a little obsessive-compulsive disorder" - I totally agree with you. I wouldn't call this OCD but it's actually imperative to eliminate errors and warnings as much as possible. The intent of warnings and errors is to draw your attention so you need to avoid becoming numb to those. Hence, removing false positives and fixing errors/warnings is a must.

Comment: @Thomas I understand your concern, I also know the need for a warning, But that's not what I'm talking about in this question. Sorry I didn't mention it earlier, this isn't actually a error, code works fine.

Comment: No, I think I get you but we still may have a misunderstanding. As I said this may be a a false positive which is only reported by the IDE (and not the compiler or any library) so it may have to be the IDE that is told to ignore this error. I wouldn't ignore all errors/warnings just because you don't know the name (and you don't even know the IDE would use the annotation for this, do you?) - so if this is specific to a certain IDE then look for a IDE-specific solution.

Comment: @Thomas I don't know whether it is Gradle or the IDE caused the error. It seems that there is no clear answer in the issue link. I only know that this error will appear in `IDEA` and `Android Studio`, I haven't tested other IDEs, in a way this may be considered `a IDE-specific`.